# android service with asynctask not stopping completely

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

I have a download service to download file with asynctask.A button is there for pause and resume.When I hit pause it should destroy service to cancel current task. I tried to achieve it by using

```
Intent download=new Intent(Download.this, DownloadService.class); getApplicationContext().stopService(download);
```

and also putting

```
stopself();
```

inside onDestroy(){} function.My problem is **DownloadTask** is not canceled when **DownloadService** is destroyed. PLease help to find the root of the problem. Thank you.

Comment: How do you download the file? With a http request or DownloadManager?

Comment: http request,i am using service therefore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cancel the AsyncTask before you stop the Service. Because the AsyncTask will work till the App process will be shut down.

Therefor you have to shutdown your HttpRequest to break this blocking call inside your AsyncTask. Hold an instance of the HttpClient as an Attribute in your AsyncTask. Define a break function in your Service which looks something like this.

```
public void stopTaskAndService(){
    yourAsyncTask.yourHttpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    yourAsyncTask.cancel(true) // prevent the onPostExecute() call
    stopself();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply i m looking at it.

Comment: I could not type **yourAsyncTask.yourHttpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();**    I just closed connection to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to see more code to know for certain what's going on.

I wonder if you'd be better served by using an IntentService instead of a Service. Did you consider this?

Comment: My onStartCommand() **code=intent.getIntExtra("code", 0);
  link=intent.getStringExtra("nLink");
  fileName=intent.getStringExtra("ntitle");
  row=intent.getLongExtra("row", 0);
  if(code==1){
   percent=intent.getStringExtra("perce");
   total=intent.getStringExtra("total");
   downloaded=intent.getStringExtra("downloaded");
  }
  
  System.out.println(row);
  Toast.makeText(this, "MyService Started ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   
  
  getfile.execute(new String[] {link,fileName});
   
  return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;**

Comment: I m stopping this service in mainactivity as **Intent download=new Intent(Download.this, DownloadService.class); 
      getApplicationContext().stopService(download);
      break;**